# wkewbview alert dialog not showing on ipad

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, uialertcontroller

I use a WKWebView.

Alert dialog works normally on iPhone, but is not visible on iPad. How can I fix this?

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler()
    }))
    
    
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {

        if let popoverPresentationController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
            
            popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
            popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
            
            popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = []

        }

    } else {
        
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }

}
```

Comment: i am java programmer. ios  progamming very very rookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of iPad you are not presenting the ViewController inside the if - let.
Move the `self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)` outside the else block.

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {

        if let popoverPresentationController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
            
            popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
            popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
            
            popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = []

        }

}
        
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

As a side-note, check if the alertController.popoverPresentationController is not nil